# Animating a Pendulum in Java using the Arc class

Tags: java, automatic-ref-counting

I am working on a problem from the book, "Introduction to Java Programming Comprehensive Version" by Dr Daniel Liang and am trying to make an animation of a pendulum. The description of the problem is "15.31 (Geometry: pendulum) Write a program that animates a pendulum swinging, as shown in Figure 15.35. Press the UP arrow key to increase the speed and the DOWN key to decrease it. Press the S key to stop animation and the R key to resume it." I am working on just the movement of the pendulum without interaction from the keyboard for now.

I used the Arc class to make the paths for both the pendulum hand and the ball. However, the pendulum is making unwanted jumping movements when it reaches the left end or right end as shown in this Youtube video of my program: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-p_S2GGxoiQ&feature=youtu.be

I then saw in someone else's code from https://github.com/razeemaharzan/pendulum-animation-javafx/blob/master/src/pendulum/fx/PendulumAnimation.java that rather than the Arc class, he used the ArcTo class for the path of the ball and the getTransforms().add(transform) method for the movement of the hand.

I understand his code but what I would like to ask is, is there a way to make the pendulum work properly with the Arc class for paths? Below is my code for your reference:

```
// For Exercise 15.31

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

public class Pendulum extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        // For the ball
        Arc pathArc = new Arc(150, 30, 150, 150, -30, -120);
        Circle circle = new Circle(0, 0, 10); 

        // For the hand
        Arc pathArc2 = new Arc(150, 30, 75, 75, -30, -120);
        Rectangle string = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2, 150);

        pane.getChildren().add(circle);
        pane.getChildren().add(string);

        // For the ball's animation
        PathTransition pt = new PathTransition();
        pt.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
        pt.setPath(pathArc);
        pt.setNode(circle);
        pt.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        pt.setAutoReverse(true);
        pt.play();

        // For the hand's animation
        PathTransition pt2 = new PathTransition(); // for the string connecting the pendulum ball
        pt2.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
        pt2.setPath(pathArc2);
        pt2.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
        pt2.setNode(string);
        pt2.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        pt2.setAutoReverse(true);
        pt2.play();

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 220);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Pendulum");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```